# Mega Upload Files not Loading

Tags: ee2, file-uploads, ftp

Our website has been using MegaUpload with EE for a year without a hitch.

However, MegaUpload has suddenly stopped uploading files for no apparent reason. The user browses to the file, selects it for upload but the progress bar doesn't move past 0%. No errors are given. Just nothing happens.

We are using ExpressionEngine v2.5.5 and MegaUpload v2.5.3.

The hosting plan has enough space and the *.mp3 files are only 2-3 megs each. The destination folder still has full write permissions.

The clients use their site to upload files for their customers on a daily basis so this is a semi-urgent one. Can anyone help!?

Cheers
Lou

Comment: any JS errors on the page? Open Chrome inspector and check it. Did you check if client is open site with the same url as used for upload action (w/ www or w/o www) - can be cross domain issue.

Comment: Could also be the version of php - many admins are updating their servers now